# Build a local multi-version ubuntu apt repository

Tags: apt, repository, localrepository

Recently,I want to build a ubuntu apt repository in company internal.
At first, I tried to use apt-mirror to build a local repository (in 20.04.4 LTS). After solving some bugs of apt-mirror, I successfully built a local repository for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, but Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS cannot use this repository,only 20.04.4 LTS can be used, but I don't know what the problem is, how can I build a repository that can be used by all versions of 20.04 (don't care minor version)?

```
root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/apt/mirror.list 
############# config ##################
#
# set base_path    /var/spool/apt-mirror
set base_path    /opt/apt-mirror/mirror
#
# set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
# set skel_path    $base_path/skel
# set var_path     $base_path/var
# set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
set defaultarch  amd64
# set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
# set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############

#deb http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse

#deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb-amd64 http://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src https://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src https://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src https://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src https://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse

clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're keeping your systems updated, there shouldn't be any difference between 20.04.2 and 20.04.4 - the point releases are when new ISOs are generated. There shouldn't be any functional difference in the systems once you've installed all the updates. So if 20.04.2 systems aren't able to use your repo, there's something wrong with your systems (or more likely, how you manage them). Fix that first.

Comment: To keep the development environment stable, I turned off automatic updates. 
There are now two versions of Ubuntu, one is 20.04.4 and the other is 20.04.2. 
There is no problem with installing software(use apt command) when these two versions use the public repository, but the local apt repository I built myself can only be used for 20.04.4, what should I do?
I can't update system.

Comment: @virgil710 I hate to say it, but what you're describing is not a good idea, for three reasons. One, it's entirely unnecessary. Ubuntu is designed to be stable and stay stable, and any change that would result in a development environment changing enough to cause problems would be a serious bug in the system. The entirety of the Ubuntu Stable Release Update process is designed to keep this very thing from happening. (continued in next comment...)

Comment: @virgil710 (...continued from last comment) Two, it's backfiring, as evidenced by the trouble you're having with a repo. Ubuntu isn't designed to see the point releases as separate, and as a result, there is no good way (that I know of) to make your repo work. Three, by not keeping your system's updated, you're leaving buggy, insecure code on your system, meaning that the apps you develop may be designed to work around bugs that no longer exist, which may cause problems for your end users, and you are at risk of having your systems compromised. (continued in next comment...)

Comment: @virgil710 (...continued from last comment) Using Ubuntu systems that are not kept up-to-date has the same problem as using an end-of-life version of Ubuntu - it's unsupported, you're likely to encounter trouble, and it may cause trouble for other people who depend on your services down the line. If you're really worried about your development environment breaking down, try running a fully updated Ubuntu system in a virtual machine and see if your environment still works perfectly fine there. If so, upgrade all your systems and the problem you're encountering will likely vanish.

Comment: First of all, I'm not talking about system upgrades, because I have to keep the development environment consistent with the business environment. It's not something I can decide alone, it's the decision of the entire team.
Secondly, my question is why the public repository is compatible with multiple versions (including different major versions, 16.04/18.04/20.04) and I want to build the same repository locally.
If you have a good note, you are welcome to say it.

Comment: @virgil710 Making a repository compatible with multiple major versions is different than making it compatible with multiple minor versions. The major versions have clear lines between them, and Ubuntu is designed to recognize those lines. There are no such lines between minor versions - 20.04.2 and 20.04.4 are the same OS, but 20.04.2 is sorely outdated. Ubuntu isn't designed to be left outdated. Sadly, if this was your employer's doing, the best solution is to talk to your employer. If they want this to work properly, they need to figure out how to safely update, and stay updated from now on.